How to reference the value of a defined property in org-mode's header-args?
Today I want to try out org-mode's tangle feature, and my requirement is as follows.
I have a go.traps.org file, and I want to organize the Go problems I've encountered there. Each code block will be tangled from a file in another project, say ~/projects/learn/go/trap/*.go. But it's too troublesome to define the following header-args for each code snippet:
:tangle ~/projects/learn/go/trap/trap-tangle-file-name.go

So I want to use properties to solve this. At the file level, I've defined the following global property:
:PROPERTIES:
:export-dir: ~/projects/learn/go/trap/
:header-args:go: :tangle ??
:END:

The ?? above is the problem I'm trying to solve. My goal is that the value of ?? should be the concatenation of :export-dir: and the current heading's title or code block's :NAME: value. How can I achieve this? Or is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

You can have arbitrary lisp code in a header-arg:
:tangle (... code ...)

The form is going to be evaluated before the block is evaluated or tangled.
So you can write a function that does what you want and then call it in the header arg:
:tangle (my/tangle-directory)

Something like this:
:PROPERTIES:
:export-dir: ~/projects/learn/go/trap/
:header-args:go: :tangle (my/tangle-directory)
:END:

* foohead
#+name: foosrc
#+begin_src go
some golang program
#+end_src


* Code

#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun my/tangle-directory ()
    (let ((name (nth 4 (org-babel-get-src-block-info t)))
          (title (nth 4 (org-heading-components))))
      (concat (org-entry-get nil "export-dir" t)
              (or name title))))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
my/tangle-directory
:end:


Evaluate the lisp source block in the Code section with C-c C-c to define the function my/tangle-directory before you tangle the go source block with C-c C-v C-t.
The above function uses the source block name if it is defined and falls back to the headline if not. It assumes that at least one of these is defined.
You could put the code of the function in the header but I prefer to keep the headers as simple as possible.
